# Cross-platform offline mindmapping

Tags: windows, linux, offline, mind-mapping

I’m looking for mind mapping software that could work on both Windows and Linux. No special features are needed, just need this software draw simple mind map.

Optionally it would be nice if I could see maps on my iPad.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. E.g.: What features do you need? What formats should be supported?

Answer (score 4):

[Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a Mind Mapping program with the following characteristics:

- Free, **Gratis** & Open Source
- Written is [Java](http://java.com/download/) so will run on:

  - Windows
  - OS-X
  - Linux
  - Others
- Mind Maps can include follow-able links
- Folding & Unfolding
- XML Data storage format
- Export to HTML, Flash & Java Applet **with folding** - At least one of which should let you view on your phone
- Export to PNG, JPG, PDF & SVG - Definitely view-able on your phone

[image][image]